# I didnt find app.config file in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, android

I didn't find **app.config** file in **visual studio 2015**.
Actually I gone to Projects - Add new items - Installed - General (in that I didn't find `app.config`)

Even if I click online download also I cannot open the link.

Comment: i didnt find app.config

Comment: No, that one also i didnt found.

Comment: What is the project type? Xamarin.Android projects do not use app.config at all.

Answer (score 0):

if it does not appear on the project new item list, then your project does not need the config file

Comment: This should be a comment